# Table overflow across right margin

Tags: tables

Can not restrict the table

```
\documentclass[pdflatex, sn-aps]{sn-jnl}% American Physical Society (APS) Reference Style
%%%% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
%Table packages
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Part of the patient data collected via the questionnaire}
\label{tab:Patient data}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular} {           c
                            c
                            c
                            c
                            c
                            c
                            c
                            c
                            c
                             }
\toprule
\thead{Patient\\Number} &\thead{$T_{before}$\\(week1)} & \thead{$T_{after}$\\(week1)}& \thead{$C_{week1}$}
& \thead{$C_{week2}$}& \thead{$C_{week3}$}& \thead{$C_{week4}$}& \thead{Overall\\improvement}&\thead{$T_{after}$\\(week4)}\\
\midrule\\
1&41&34&17.07&17.26&20.62&23.67&6.60&32 \\
\addlinespace
2&41&41&0.00&3.49&6.47&7.16&7.16&35 \\
\addlinespace
3&41&34&17.07&18.88&19.87&21.12&4.05&30 \\
\addlinespace
4&89&88&1.12&3.27&6.13&8.30&7.18&81 \\
\addlinespace
12&50&50&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&0.00&50 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
 \end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/1090

Comment: Too geeky for a beginner like me

Comment: sorry that's how the site works. If you try something and get an error you could ask a more specific question about the error you get, but generic table-too-wide questions can't really have any new answers.  Just put `\footnotesize`  before the `\begin{tabular}` so it is smaller.

Comment: You could also change environment from `tabular`  to `tabular*` and add "forced" width, with flexible spaces between columns (see [this page](https://latexref.xyz/tabular.html)), as an example the definition could be: `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c c c c c c c c} ... \end{tabular*}`. But your table will be too narrow and probably will not look well.

Comment: Adding \footnotesize before \begin{tabular} had no effect on the output.

Comment: Temporarily adjusted by shortening the headings.

Comment: @Celdor Thank you for mentioning exactly where to start.

Comment: @Bukaida Np. You may also need to add `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` before the `tabular`/`tabular*` environment. BTW adding `\footnotesize` as David mentioned sets smaller font inside a table and it should work.

Comment: @Bukaida If creating tables are a pain for you, you can try this tool: https://www.latex-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you shorten the header entries (e.g., by abbreviating "week" as "wk", using roman rather than math-italic lettering, and not over-using **bold** lettering), use `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}`, and employ a `tabular*` environment. That way, you won't even to employ `\footnotesize`. Oh, and I would use the `S` column type for 5 of the 9 columns in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[sn-aps]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out amount of intercolumn whitespace
\caption{Part of patient data collected via questionnaire}
\label{tab:Patient data}  
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
     S[table-format=2.0]
     cc 
     *{4}{S[table-format=2.2]} 
     cc }
\toprule
{\thead{Patient\\Number}} &
\thead{$T_{\textrm{before}}$ \\(wk1)} & 
\thead{$T_{\textrm{after}}$  \\(wk1)}& 
$C_{\textrm{wk1}}$& 
$C_{\textrm{wk2}}$& 
$C_{\textrm{wk3}}$& 
$C_{\textrm{wk4}}$& 
\thead{Overall\\improve't}&
\thead{$T_{\textrm{after}}$  \\(wk4)}\\
\midrule
1 &41&34&17.07&17.26&20.62&23.67&6.60&32 \\
2 &41&41& 0.00& 3.49& 6.47& 7.16&7.16&35 \\
3 &41&34&17.07&18.88&19.87&21.12&4.05&30 \\
4 &89&88& 1.12& 3.27& 6.13& 8.30&7.18&81 \\
12&50&50& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00& 0.00&0.00&50 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OP has slightly larger vertical spaces between rows. It would be worth adding redefinition of the `arraystretch` to achieve the similar effect.

Comment: Thanks Mico. Although I managed to shorten the table following Celdor's suggestions but was struggling with the headers. This one is quite neat. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Celdor - Thanks. Indeed, I removed all of the `\addlinespace` directives that were in the OP's code. I agree with you that increasing the value of `\arraystretch` is the way to go if the spacing between every single line should be increased.